# How to handle http errors (FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1))

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to handle this kind of error message? Why is it coming? Is that issue? I called below method every 10 seconds.

```
   checkQuick(String url, String token) async {
    result =
        (await HelperDatabase1().displayGetUserPreference()).elementAt(0)?.data;
    final response = await http.get(
      '$url/nativeapi/v1.0/User/GetUserPreference',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
    );
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    GetUserPreference model = GetUserPreference.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    var data = GetUserPreference(data: model.data);
    //result = data.data;

      if (result != data.data) {
     //  await HelperDatabase1().updateGetUserPreference(1, data.data);
        print('inside');
        await HelperDatabase1().deleteGetUserPreference();
        await HelperDatabase1().storeGetUserPreference(url, token);
      }
  }
```

below error message coming some times.

```
E/flutter ( 7148): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 7148): 
E/flutter ( 7148): ^
E/flutter ( 7148):
```

> E/flutter ( 7148): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail
> (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1392:5) E/flutter ( 7148): #1
> _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:510:7) E/flutter ( 7148): #2      _parseJson
> (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:30:10) E/flutter ( 7148): #3
> JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:493:36) E/flutter ( 7148):
>
> ## 4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:151:41) E/flutter ( 7148): #5      _ListPageState.checkQuick
>
> (package:reborn_next_job02/ui/AssetRegisters.dart:153:31) E/flutter (
> 7148):  E/flutter ( 7148): #6
> _ListPageState.initState. (package:reborn_next_job02/ui/AssetRegisters.dart:47:7) E/flutter (
> 7148): #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38) E/flutter
> ( 7148): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
> E/flutter ( 7148): #9      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
> (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7) E/flutter ( 7148): #10
> _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:968:26) E/flutter ( 7148): #11     _rootRunUnary
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13) E/flutter ( 7148): #12
> _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19) E/flutter ( 7148): #13     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:952:26) E/flutter ( 7148): #14
> _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19) E/flutter ( 7148): #15     _Timer._handleMessage
> (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5) E/flutter ( 7148): #16
> _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)

Answer (score 2):

Check the response.statusCode before if it is 200.
Looks like the response.body is empty because the call failed, so json.decode(response.body) throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It might be from the server end. I used to work with a ruby backend that requires '.json' added at the end of url path. Give that a try.